# Drag and drop using the notebook touchpad?

Tags: laptop, touchpad, drag-and-drop

How can I drag and drop using the notebook touchpad?

*I'm using Windows Vista on a Dell Inspiron*

Comment: would be helpful some other time ..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Double-tap, but hold the second tap. Release to drop the item.

Answer (score 2):

This is dependent on the driver you use.

Your best bet to start is to take a look at "Control Panel" > "Mouse" and then having a look through the settings.

But as sblair said, by default - if you have tap to click on, you double tap holding the second then drag and drop to where you want... so +1 to sblair.