# How to deactivate drag and drop with touchpad?

Tags: touchpad, thinkpad, drag-and-drop

I want to be able to drag and drop by using the hardware mouse-button. I want to be able to click by tapping on the touch-pad (and of course clicking by using the hardware-button should also be possible).

But I would wish to make it impossible to drag and drop by only using the touch pad. (I always do accidental drag and dropping with the touchpad).

So I want to disable touchpad drag and drop.

I am using a Thinkpad X380 Yoga with Windows 10 (and I at the moment I am adding an Ubuntu 18.04 partition as well).
I didn't find this option in Windows. I would like to have the described behavior in Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: Just a guess: Decreasing the touchpad's sensitivity is probably enough to avoid the unintended *dropping*.

Comment: Thank your for your advice, but I already did this and I am still marking texts and dragging and dropping accidentally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution for Windows 10 with the help of this answer: [Drag and drop using the notebook touchpad?](https://superuser.com/questions/80614/drag-and-drop-using-the-notebook-touchpad?rq=1) (This is the answer to kind of the opposite question)

Deactivating the option "zur Mehrauswahl zweimal tippen und ziehen"(in English it is probably called something like "multi-selecting by double tapping and dragging") in the Windows touchpad settings helped me a lot. Now it is still possibly to drag and drop by clicking the touchpad but not by (double-)tapping the touchpad. I think I always accidently dragged and dropped by double tapping the touchpad. I think I don't click the touchpad by accident.
[OptionToDeactivateScreenshot.jpg](https://ibb.co/mbf8Sp)
Until now I haven't known that clicking and tapping the touchpad is something different.